# Redis publish - Wrong number of argument for 'set'

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis

I'm trying to use websockets with Django for small parts of my application.

Trying the [first example](http://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#subscribe-to-broadcast-notifications) to broadcast a message with [django-websocket-redis](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis)

```py
from ws4redis.publisher import RedisPublisher
redis_publisher = RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True)
redis_publisher.publish_message('Hello World')
```

I'm actually receiving the message into subscribed clients but I'm getting this error:

> wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
>   [...]
>   **Exception location** my_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py in read_response, line 344

(traced from the `publish_message()` call)

My versions:

```
Django==1.6.2
django-websocket-redis==0.4.0
redis==2.9.1
```

Can someone help me to debug that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally set the expiration time to 0 as a workaround

```
WS4REDIS_EXPIRE = 0
```

This prevents ws4redis to store anything in redis.

---

Fixed since [`0.4.1`](https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis/releases/tag/0.4.1)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a bug.

Fix:

in `ws4redis.redis_store.RedisStore` in `publish_message`, change

```
self._connection.set(channel, message, ex=expire)
```

to

```
self._connection.setex(channel, expire, message)
```

the redis `SET` command does not take a 3rd argument. What I believe was meant was to set a value that expires after a number of seconds, which is the redis `SETEX` command. The py-redis `setex` method is called like `setex(name, time, value)`.

This resolves the "Wrong number of argument for 'set'" error.

ref: https://github.com/jrief/django-websocket-redis/pull/30